# Getting the dirty region inside draw()

Tags: android

If I invalidate() a part of my custom view with a dirty rect parameter, how do I get the dirty rect inside the draw() method? The clipping rect of the canvas is not the same - in my experience, it's typically few times larger.

Answer (score 3):

If the dirty rect is not the same as the one you passed to invalidate(), it is because another View or region of the screen was also invalidated.

Answer (score 2):

get the clipRect from the passed in Canvas object to onDraw method. This clipRect (Canvas::getClipBounds) is actually the invalidated Rect.

The clipRect is larger sometimes because different invalidated areas are unioned together so that one event is fired instead of firing multiple for performance reasons.

Comment: In this particular case, there were no other invalidates. The test is very clean - the app sits tight for as long as I wish, then I tap the screen. This causes a redraw. There cannot possibly be another pending invalidation.

Comment: I have the same experience here. getClipRect returns the boundary of the entire view instead of the small rect that I passed to invalidate.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct - my sample app sets a small rectangle but Canvas.getClipBounds() always returns the bounds for the whole view.

Comment: According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8947772/1942069
It seems using hardware accelerated views will set the clip bounds to the entire view. However, only the parts that intersect the clip rect will be drawn anyway.