# Android - Fade out bitmap image on canvas

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-canvas, fadeout

I am drawing a scaled bitmap onto a canvas and would like to fade my image out at a specified time.

Basically, when my character image goes over a certain section of the canvas, I require the character image to slowly fade away (3 seconds), before the page automatically re-directs to the next java class.

Currently, my image simply redirects to the new java class, please see below some code to how I am creating my image.

```
Resources res = getResources();
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, res.getDisplayMetrics());
imgSpacing = (int) px / 2;
int size = (int) ((PhoneWidth / 5) - px);

chrImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.character);
chrImg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(chrImg, size, size, true);
```

Then within the canvas onDraw:

```
if(indexX == mazeFinishX && indexY == mazeFinishY)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(finish, j * totalCellWidth, i * totalCellHeight, null);
    // As soon as the character moves over this square they are automatically re-directed to new page
    // This is where I want to fade the character image out before the re-direct
}
```

I have looked online, however cannot quite work out how to get the fading to work for my drawable image fetched from my games resources drawable folder. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you think there's a possibility you will want to change the fade animation down the road, such as scaling and/or rotating, then you should go with an animation XML.

But for just a quick bitmap fade, you can repeatedly post delayed invalidation messages. You probably want to limit your invalidated area to just where your character bitmap is:

```
private static final int FADE_MILLISECONDS = 3000; // 3 second fade effect
private static final int FADE_STEP = 120;          // 120ms refresh

// Calculate our alpha step from our fade parameters
private static final int ALPHA_STEP = 255 / (FADE_MILLISECONDS / FADE_STEP);

// Initializes the alpha to 255
private Paint alphaPaint = new Paint();

// Need to keep track of the current alpha value
private int currentAlpha = 255;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    ...
    if(indexX == mazeFinishX && indexY == mazeFinishY) {

        // Drawing your wormhole?
        int x = j * totalCellWidth;
        int y = i * totalCellHeight;
        canvas.drawBitmap(finish, x, y, null);

        if (currentAlpha > 0) {

           // Draw your character at the current alpha value
           canvas.drawBitmap(chrImg, x, y, alphaPaint);

           // Update your alpha by a step
           alphaPaint.setAlpha(currentAlpha);
           currentAlpha -= ALPHA_STEP;

           // Assuming you hold on to the size from your createScaledBitmap call
           postInvalidateDelayed(FADE_STEP, x, y, x + size, y + size);

        } else {
           // No character draw, just reset your alpha paint
           currentAlpha = 255;
           alphaPaint.setAlpha(currentAlpha);

           // Now do your redirect
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I'd recommend putting the constants FADE_MILLISECONDS and FADE_STEP into res/integers.xml just so they aren't hard-coded.

Comment: I have implemented your above code and the fading is working correctly. However the issue here is the fact that my re-direct is not working. It hits the function with the redirect code, however seems to ignore it, any ideas?

Comment: I added a "currentAlpha" field, using setAlpha/getAlpha probably wasn't working with anything other than an alpha step of 1.

Answer (score 3):

The best way for me to explain this is provide a full custom view example that you can pull the pieces from that you need.  Below is a view that accomplishes this.

```
public class CharacterView extends View {

    private Paint mCharacterPaint;
    private Bitmap mCharacterBitmap;
    private Transformation mTransformation;
    private AlphaAnimation mFadeOut;

    public CharacterView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CharacterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CharacterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        //This would be your character image instead
        mCharacterBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        //We need a paint to efficiently modify the alpha
        mCharacterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        //This is needed to house the current value during the animation
        mTransformation = new Transformation();
        //Construct an animation that will do all the timing math for you
        mFadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
        mFadeOut.setDuration(500);
        //Use a listener to trigger the end action
        mFadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //Trigger your action to change screens here.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //In this example, touching the view triggers the animation
            // your code would run this sequence when the character reaches the
            // appropriate coordinates (P.S. I would not advocate putting this code
            // inside of onDraw()
            mFadeOut.start();
            mFadeOut.getTransformation(System.currentTimeMillis(), mTransformation);
            invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //...existing drawing code...

        canvas.drawBitmap(mCharacterBitmap, 0, 0, mCharacterPaint);
        if (mFadeOut.hasStarted() && !mFadeOut.hasEnded()) {
            mFadeOut.getTransformation(System.currentTimeMillis(), mTransformation);
            //Keep drawing until we are done
            mCharacterPaint.setAlpha((int)(255 * mTransformation.getAlpha()));
            invalidate();
        } else {
            //Reset the alpha if animation is canceled
            mCharacterPaint.setAlpha(255);
        }
    }
}
```

The most efficient way to dynamically modify the transparency of what you draw is to apply it using a `Paint` drawing to your `Canvas`.  You will need to continually `invalidate()` the view with each frame transition to get the animation to display until the character is gone.  The example uses an `Animation` object and a `Transformation` object to handle all of the timing math to make the animation actually look good.

The gist here is that you start the animation via some external trigger (I wouldn't recommend doing the check for when to fade out in `onDraw()`, probably better in the place where those character locations are updated.  In my example, for simplicity sake, I started this when the view to touched.

This trigger starts the animation and gets the initial transformation value, then `invalidate()` triggers a new `onDraw()`.  While the animation is running, `onDraw()` is repeated due to the `invalidate()` and each iteration the alpha on the paint decreases slightly.

When the animation is finished, it will call the `AnimationListener` for you, so you can trigger the screen transition inside of `onAnimationEnd()`.

Comment: You should only invalidate the area where the character is being redrawn.

Comment: This can be a nice optimization if the overall view is large.  Although in many common cases (such as with hardware acceleration enabled) dirty rects are actually ignored; so it's generally not worth the effort of including unless performance warrants.

Comment: This answer from one of the Android developers seems to contradict your assertion that hardware acceleration ignores dirty regions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233830/partial-invalidation-in-custom-android-view-with-hardware-acceleration

Comment: I'd definitely trust Romain's word on the subject above all.  In fact, the case of Activity resume he describes is what I was thinking of.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
        if(indexX == mazeFinishX && indexY == mazeFinishY)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(finish, j * totalCellWidth, i * totalCellHeight, null);
            // As soon as the character moves over this square they are automtically re-directs to new page
            new CountDownTimer(0500, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAlpha(25);
canvas.drawBitmap(chrImg, 0, 0, paint);
                }
            }.start();
            new CountDownTimer(0500, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAlpha(45);
canvas.drawBitmap(chrImg, 0, 0, paint);             }
            }.start();
            new CountDownTimer(0500, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAlpha(70);
canvas.drawBitmap(chrImg, 0, 0, paint);             }
            }.start();
            new CountDownTimer(0500, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAlpha(100);
canvas.drawBitmap(chrImg, 0, 0, paint);             }
            }.start();
            // This is where I want to fade the character image out before the re-direct
            new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent i = new Intent(currentclass.this, nextClass.class);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

this will make your bitmap becomes transparent ( the alpha will be 100 ) .. and then redirect to the next class after 3 seconds.

**Update:** 
for the bitmap you can't use .setAlpha so we must use a paint, so we created a new paint each time then set the bitmap with the paint. but if you have an imageView you can use .setalpha

Comment: This works in delaying the redirect, however I want to make it so the image slowly fades away. Esentially, I have a worm hole image and want the character image to disappear into that via some sort on animation (I was thinking fading the image away).

Comment: Just tried your code, however realised that as it is a bitmap from the drawable resources you cannot use setAlpha. Is there another way, please see my orginal code to replicate the image.