# Why does partial invalidate span the entire View?

Tags: android, android-view, android-view-invalidate

I am trying to partially invalidate an android View. I use View.invalidate( l, t, b, r ) and it appears to invalidate vertically (top and bottom) values correctly, however, no matter which left and right values I use, it invalidates entire across the View.

For example, my view is gray. I wish to invalidate the green area, however, it invalidates the green and red area. It always spans the entire horizontal direction entirely across the View. I have attempted to put small values such as View.invalidate( 0, 0, 50, 50 ) and it still causes this behavior.

[Image Link (not enough rep to post images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87bYi.png)

Why is this happening?

Comment: does it work the same regardless of layer type you use (View#setLayerType)?

Comment: Setting it to hardware appears to work but "software" and "none" do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior changed with hardware accelaration, the default after Honeycomb. Now when you `invalidate()` a view providing a dirty region, the clip bound is not set (`canvas.getClipBounds()`). However, only objects intersecting the dirty region will be redrawn.

See for reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8947772/913286) answer by Romain Guy, the author of the rendering pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :) I was pulling my hair out trying to research exactly what is going on